# How get 'Priority' of Notification from 'Status Bar Notifications'

Tags: android, android-notifications

I am try to read/get all properties of notifications from *Notification Bar* using **NotificationListenerService**. Now i want to know the *priority* of each notification.So,that i can sort all the notifications and show them by their priority in my application.

I have already ***StatusBarNotification mStatusBarNotification*** and ***Bundle extras = mStatusBarNotification.getNotification().extras;*** By using these variables am i get the priority? If yes how?

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

By using int priority = mStatusBarNotification.getNotification().priority;
we can get the *priority* of Notification